# How to implement a jQuery .post inside of an if statement

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, radio-button

I'm currently trying to have users click a radio button, which then automatically updates a status in our database; however I'm having a little problem with the .post function.

```
<script>
$(function(){
  $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
   if ($(this).is(':checked'))
   {
    var value = ($(this).val());

    alert(value);
   }
  });
});  
</script>
```

This is the code that does what it has to do and the right value is being passed on to the variable.

However, when modifying it to this:

```
<script>
$(function(){
 $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
  if ($(this).is(':checked'))
  {
   var value = ($(this).val());

   $.post('/choices.php',  
   { 
    choice: value,
    auction_id: '<?php echo $sale['Product']['id']; ?>',
    token: '<?php echo md5(session_id().$session->read('Auth.User.id')); ?>' 
   }

   alert(value);
   }
 });
});  
</script>
```

The values are not being passed on to the PHP file and also, the alert is not working anymore; so I'm suspecting that I'm not implementing the $.post function correctly. If so, what's the correct way of utilizing jQuery's .post function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
$(function(){
 $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
  if ($(this).is(':checked'))
  {
   var value = ($(this).val());

   $.post('/choices.php',  
   { 
    choice: value,
    auction_id: '<?php echo $sale['Product']['id']; ?>',
    token: '<?php echo md5(session_id().$session->read('Auth.User.id')); ?>' 
   }); // append ")" here

   alert(value);
   }
 });
});  
</script>
```

then this ajax call completed with out waiting `alert(value);` statement

or you can do for run `alert(value);` when ajax call

```
completed:

<script>
$(function(){
 $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
  if ($(this).is(':checked'))
  {
   var value = ($(this).val());

   $.post('/choices.php',  
   { 
    choice: value,
    auction_id: '<?php echo $sale['Product']['id']; ?>',
    token: '<?php echo md5(session_id().$session->read('Auth.User.id')); ?>' 
   }, function(data){
    alert(value);
   });   
   }
 });
});  
</script>
```

Comment: Although my problem could be fixed in multiple ways (as shown above), this one worked for me and was the first one I tried. Thanks for pointing it out. jQuery is still pretty unknown territory for me.

Answer (score 0):

You should add callback method for the post method. It will look like:

```
$.post('/choices.php', {
        choice: value,
        auction_id: "<?php echo $sale['Product ']['id ']; ?>",
        token: "<?php echo md5(session_id().$session->read('Auth.User.id ')); ?>"
    },
    function(data) {
        value = data;
    });
```

Also, you should properly format Php code (quotation marks), as I did above.

Comment: Sorry, I just read this back, but I don't think ' or " would make a big difference.